# Unable to generate java.util.Calendar from xsd - getting XmlGregorianCalendar

Tags: jaxb, xsd, wsdl, cxf

Is it possible to generate entities with Claendar type fields from xsd files? I am trying both xs:date and xs:dateTime but still getting XMLGregarionCalendar. I am using cxf-codegen-plugin and jaxb bninding.
Thanks.
Paul.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you generate your objects you can use a JAXB binding file, as demonstrated in Example 7 of the [cxf-codegen-plugin documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html).  Depending on what type you want to use (Calendar, Date, etc.), you will need to specify an appropriate adapter.  To use Calendar, JAXB provides the adapter javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter. To use it with dateTime, date, and time, the JAXB bindings file should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="2.1"
              xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">

    <jxb:globalBindings>
        <!-- use Calendar instead of XMLGregorianCalendar -->
        <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
            parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime"
            printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime"/>

        <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xs:date"
            parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDate"
            printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDate"/>

        <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xs:time"
            parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseTime"
            printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printTime"/>

    </jxb:globalBindings>        
</jxb:bindings>
```

If you want to use Date instead, CXF provides org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter in cxf-xjc-runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Patrick's answer, here is the XJC equivalent:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1"
              xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">

    <jaxb:globalBindings>
       <!-- use Calendar Date instead of XMLGregorianCalendar -->
       <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                 parseMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.parseDateTime"
                 printMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.printDateTime"/>

       <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:date"
                 parseMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.parseDate"
                 printMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.printDate"/>

       <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:time"
                 parseMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.parseTime"
                 printMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.printTime"/>

    </jaxb:globalBindings>         
</jaxb:bindings>
```