# cxf wsdl2java generating ArrayOf<Type> instead of Type[]

Tags: java, xml, xsd, cxf, xjb

I am using cxf wsdl2java commandline command in order to generate the client (java files). My xsd looks something like this -

```
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfString">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="string" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>   
<xs:element name="ConfirmSMSResults">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="smsIds" type="tns:ArrayOfString"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The generated java file `ConfirmSMSResults.java` has something like this

`@XmlElement(required = true)
    protected ArrayOfString smsIds;`

where it should be `protected String[] smsIds;`

I had a similar problem with the `date` data type defined in the `xsd` file, which got converted to `XMLGregorianCalendar`. However, I solved it by using an external `xjb` file and defining the binding there. It could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287429/unable-to-generate-java-util-calendar-from-xsd-getting-xmlgregoriancalendar). I can't seem to find something similar for my issue with the Array.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't the problem actually this `type="tns:ArrayOfString"`?  The `ArrayOfString` is actually an object that it is creating for you from your complexType.

Comment: @jbx oh shoot, how did I not see that. I fixed the problem. I will post the solution below just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying that

> it should be `protected String[] smsIds`

when in fact your XSD is not saying so.

Your XSD is saying that `smsIDs` is a `complexType` of type `ArrayOfString` which is defined at the top, and CXF will create a corresponding object `ArrayOfString`. Inside it there is an element called `string` which can occur multiple times, so probably you will find your array / list inside the `ArrayOfString` object it generates for your XSD.

If you want to remove that wrapper object, in your XSD you have to change this:

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="smsIds" type="tns:ArrayOfString"/>
```

to

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="smsIds" type="xsd:string"/>
```

Comment: Thanks I realised what went wrong. I have posted the solution, didn't see yours until now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it seems like I missed something. The `type` property refers to `ArrayofString` object, instead it should be `xs:string`. There seems to be no need of `ArrayOfStrings` object. Also, `maxOccurs` should be equal to `unbounded`. End result -

```
<xs:element name="ConfirmSMSResults">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" name="smsIds" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I also added `collectionType="indexed"`to my xjb file. So it looks something like this now `<jaxb:globalBindings collectionType ="indexed">`